# Spring Boot + Hibernate + PostgreSQL как сделать правильный метод в репозитории?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

Всем привет, Я получаю стандартным методом репозитория список всех записей которые имеют поле parent_id == null, для определения родительской задачи в своем приложении, затем stream`ом пробегаюсь по этому списку, беру необходимые мне поля из основного списка и добавляя еще одно новое поле, создаю новый список, использую для этого вот такой способ для создания response клиенту:

```
@GetMapping
        public List<TaskResponse> getTitleTask(@CurrentUser UserPrincipal userPrincipal) {
            User currentUser = userRepo.findById(userPrincipal.getId()).get();
            List<TaskResponse> responseList = taskRepo
                    .findAllByUserAndParentIdNullOrderByIdAsc(currentUser)
                    .stream()
                    .map(task -> new TaskResponse(
                            task.getId(),
                            task.getName(),
                            task.getColor(),
                            task.getImageUrl(),
                            task.getCreated(),
                            task.getExpiredDate(),
                            task.getIsDone(),
                            taskRepo.countByParentId(task)
                    )).collect(Collectors.toList());
            return responseList;
        }
```

Task.class:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Task {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 30, min = 3)
    private String name;

    @Column(length = 4096)
    private String description;
    private String color;
    private String imageUrl;
    private LocalDateTime created;
    private LocalDateTime expiredDate;
    @NotNull
    private Boolean isDone;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_task_id")
    private Task parentId;
```

Способ рабочий, но мне не нравиться что при проходе цикла я каждый раз обращаюсь к базе, чтобы получить количество дочерних задач текущего Task. подскажите как будет правильно сделать?

Таблица:

```
create table if not exists task(
id             bigint  not null
constraint task_pkey primary key,
color          varchar(255),
created        timestamp,
description    varchar(4096),
expired_date   timestamp,
image_url      varchar(255),
is_done        boolean not null,
name           varchar(30),
parent_task_id bigint constraint task_constraint
references task,
user_id        bigint constraint user_constraint
references usr);
```

[image: Task]